# better selenium xpath is expecting

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm trying to create xpath expression which will work with selenium using following html snippet.
Below is table contains various row that gets incremented with uniquely generatedid(for example in following snippet that id is 1000).

Selenium has created following expressions when row of id 1000 was added in table. However instead of using id, I want to create xpath by using 3rd data element in row which is (MyName) in html snippet.

Comment: This is what selenium has created. 
//tr[@id='1000']/td[1]/a[1]/img
//tr[@id='1000']/td[1]/span/a/img
//tr[@id='1000']/td[1]/a[2]/img
//tr[@id='1000']/td[1]/a[3]/img
//tr[@id='1000']/td[4]/input
//tr[@id='1000']/td[5]/input

Comment: and actual snippet is as follows:

Comment: <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="href.jsp?id=1000" title="alter"><img src="alter.png" alt="alter" style="border: 0px none;"></a><span class="ats"> <a href="#" title="delete" onclick="delete(2,1000); return false;"><img src="delete.png" alt="delete"></a></span> <a href="#" title="cpy" onclick="apy(1000,2); return false;"><img src="cpy.png" alt="cpy""></a> <a href="ap.jsp" title="report"><img src="cht.png" alt="rpt""></a></td>
<td>1000</td>
<td>MyName</td>
<td><input name="prd" onchange="chgsts(true, this,1000 );" type="checkbox"></td>

Answer (score 1):

A possible suggestion is to not use xpath whenever possible.

http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the places in the XPATH where it is referring to the row by its ID to its relative position in the table.

In all of your XPATHs, you would change  tr[@id='1000'] to tr[3]

Your first example XPATH would look liek this:

//**tr[3]**/td[1]/a[1]/img //tr[@id='1000']/td[1]/span/a/img

Your second example would follow similarly:

//tr[3]/td[1]/span/a/img

As would your third:

//tr[3]/td[1]/a[2]/img

Hopefully you are now able change the rest of them.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply ..but expression you provided doesn't work. I'm trying to search workaround for it.